# DB2 CTE Recursion on one table, 6 levels

Tags: sql, recursion, db2, common-table-expression

I have to write a recursion on a db2 table that contains a parent/child relationship in its column values. it's a terrible design but unfortunately I have no control over that. It's a data dump from SalesForce.

Each record in the dump table represents a level of product code groupings. Starting from the top level Indutstrial, AG, OIL, etc, each group has subgroups with group codes until reaching the bottom level that contains the actual product code. 
Given the product code (STCC_RECORD_ID) I need to retrieve the top parent's GROUP_CODE. I am stuck, any insight would be greatly appreciated. Here is my latest version of the SQL:

```
WITH X(ID,STCC_RECORD_ID,PARENT_ID,GROUP_CODE,SEG_NAME) AS 
(
SELECT P.ID,P.STCC_RECORD_ID,P.PARENT_ID,P.GROUP_CODE,P.SEG_NAME
        FROM HB_EXTRACT.SEGMENTATION P
        WHERE STCC_RECORD_ID='0113211' 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,STCC_RECORD_ID,PARENT_ID,GROUP_CODE,SEG_NAME
        FROM x
        WHERE x.PARENT_ID = ID
) 
SELECT * FROM X
```

Here is the output from that. Only the bottom record shows:
[image]

This is the desired output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have to use a bottom-up approach.

```
WITH X(ID,STCC_RECORD_ID,PARENT_ID,GROUP_CODE,SEG_NAME, Level) AS 
(
SELECT P.ID,P.STCC_RECORD_ID,P.PARENT_ID,P.GROUP_CODE,P.SEG_NAME, 0
        FROM HB_EXTRACT.SEGMENTATION P
        WHERE STCC_RECORD_ID='0113211' 
UNION ALL
SELECT P.ID,P.STCC_RECORD_ID,P.PARENT_ID,P.GROUP_CODE,P.SEG_NAME, Level+1
        FROM x, HB_EXTRACT.SEGMENTATION P
        WHERE x.STCC_RECORD_ID=P.PARENT_ID
        AND Level<7
) 
SELECT * FROM X
WHERE Level>4
```

In each iteration, you join the next level (parent) based on the current record. The level column is used to later on select a specific layer of table X.

Comment: Why the level restrictions?  The OP can't know, ahead of time, how deep the tree is.  Oh, and _please_, don't use the comma-separated `FROM` clause - just explicitly list out the `JOIN`.

Comment: It says 6 levels and it is a precaution for testing.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with a couple of things I was missing like level... but it's still just returning the bottom (top?) record, same as before. It's almost like it's not matching the parent_id, but when I look at it manually they definitely match. Or, it's not doing the recursion. I'll keep at it, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse when I try to use any type of Join it errors and says 'an explicit join including an ON clause is not allowed in the fullselect of the recursive operation'

Comment: Update: My apologies, your solution worked fine. We had the parent_id trying to match the STCC_RECORD_ID instead of just ID. It's works like a champ, you're my hero. Thanks!

Comment: @CalHarris - I'd forgotten about that particular restriction, although I can't recall if it affects all platforms of DB2 or not.  Note that some versions of DB2 also support the `CONNECT BY` operator, which would also work here.